# Issue when importing from a package in visual studio code

Tags: python, directory, package, importerror

I am using Visual Studio Code, and when I create a package directory, it is not recognized and gives me an error

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyshop settings**

Excuse my lack of explanation as I am still new to learning

I got this error after creating a directory and trying to import from it.

```
`from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','pyshop settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('products/',include ('"products.urls'))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Your line `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','pyshop settings')`  set env variable to define where to find django settings (as per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings))

So this need to point to your settings modules, like:

```py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
```

If your settings are in mysite/settings.py

The error state that it wasn't able to find any "pyshop settings" module (understand python file)